# Does the macOS 10.13 (High Sierra) installer install a Recovery Parition?

Tags: high-sierra, recovery

Just upgraded from 10.12.6 to 10.13.3. Everything seemed to go smoothly... except I see I have no Recovery Partition any more - holding down Option at startup just gets me my macOS and BootCamp boot options. Here is the results of `mount`:

```
~>mount
/dev/disk1s1 on / (apfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s4 on /private/var/vm (apfs, local, noexec, journaled, noatime, nobrowse)
/dev/disk0s3 on /Volumes/Bootcamp (ntfs, local, read-only, noowners)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
```

So is no Recovery Partition expected with 10.13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With macOS 10.13 (High Sierra), the recovery partition is moved to inside an APFS container. This container houses your main OS partition (what used to be HFS+ in macOS 10.12 (Sierra) and older) and the recovery partition, as well as a swap partition called `VM` (**V**irtual **M**emory) and a `Preboot` partition. You can see these by running the command `diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         499.9 GB

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +499.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume macOS                   496.0 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 21.9 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                517.8 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
```

You can see it listed here as `disk1s3`. None of the partitions in the container are automounted other than `disk1s1`, though you still can mount them (taking the recovery partition as an example) by running `diskutil mount disk1s3`.

The recovery partition is still accessed the same way as before at startup (holding ⌘R at the startup chime).

Comment: Thanks - I see the same thing from `diskutil list` (albeit with BootCamp) - but do you see the Recovery Partition as an option when you hold down the Option key at boot time?

Comment: No, normally that is not the case even before High Sierra. The recovery partition does not possess an entry in the EFI partition.

Comment: That is incorrect - up to and including 10.12 (Sierra), the Recovery Partition was an option at boot time when holding down the Option key.

Comment: Interesting. I must have misremembered; thanks for the correction! :) In that case, I suspect a limitation in displaying multiple boot options from a single APFS container, though I do not know for sure. In any event, it lacks an EFI partition entry in High Sierra.